# Notify client app when admin consent is revoked from Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365api

I have a Rails app to which a user can connect their Office365 account.

In the scenario where the user has a work account and their admin gives consent to the required permissions, but afterwards revokes this consent by deleting the app from
**Azure Active Directory >> Enterprise Applications**

How will my app know that the access has been revoked so that it can show an appropriate message to the user? Is there a webhook call for this? Is there a way to figure it out from a particular error response when the API calls are made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the customer has removed the app from their tenant, you will no longer be able to obtain an access token to make API calls. The exact error message/experience depends on how exactly you are obtaining access token.